# C++ data structure declaration

Tags: c++, struct

```
struct movies_t {
  string title;
  int year;
} films [3];
```

From this tutorial:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/

If I understand correctly films is the declaration of an array of four data structures of the type movies_t. Is that correct or is there something else to this?

Thanks...

Comment: Seems correct, only there are three elements, not four.

Comment: It's 3 data structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If I understand correctly films is the declaration of an array of four data structures of the type movies_t.
```

Nope. It's having size `3` with index `0`, `1` and `2.`

```
films [0]
films [1]
films [2]
```